# Spark Dataframe order by multiple columns with different data types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can multiple columns with different data types be sorted in spark DataFrame?

I am using windows functions to group by and sort.

My Code :

```
val sortCols = sortKeyList.map(col(_).desc)

val sortW = Window.partitionBy(pkCol: _*).orderBy(sortCols:_*)
```

Sort keys are of different data types and hence i get below error,

*`User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(t_releasetime DESC && dateto DESC)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in`*

Spark version I am using is `1.5.2`.

Comment: I was not able to get it correctly, can you give me an example on what the input is and whats the output that you expect ?

Comment: This actually works fine in spark 2.0.0 so it might simply be a fixed bug...

Comment: Hey, have you sorted this out?

Comment: Apart from the code above i used rank function and then selected the rows which i need.                                                                                     val finalDf = srcDf.withColumn("rank", rowNumber.over(sortW)).where("rank = 1").cache()